# Sprite transparency in Quartz, Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-graphics, osx-tiger

In Java I can make a background rect colored blue. I can then draw a load of sprites also with blue as the background color. I can then make it so that particular blue does not show up when drawing to the canvas or view as it is here, how do I do this in Quartz in Objective C?

Comment: Why do you need to use Quartz?  I suggest you run a search for such a basic question.

Comment: Why do you need to use blue as the background color? Why not just leave the background transparent?

Comment: A: I need to use quartz because this is a Power PC based app. B: I wouldn't be asking here if I hadn't already searched. C: I could go transparent and I will if I cant find another solution, but thats a huge amount of images I would need to alter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1454358-cgimagecreatewithmaskingcolors) to create a copy of an image with the blue pixels changed to transparent.  This function was (according to the documentation) added in macOS 10.4 (Tiger). It is discussed in[“Masking an Image with Color” in the *Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHCADE).

Comment: Thanks so much, this looks like exactly what I need. I'll try it tomorrow